# Boolean syntax in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, boolean

I have a few boolean variables in CakePHP - `Live` and `Flagged`.
Live is working fine - but the rest are not:

```
 <?php echo $item['Item']['live']; ?> // 1
 <?php echo $item['Item']['flagged']; ?> // 1
 <?php echo $item['Item']['live'] ? '<span class="label success">Live</span>' : ''; ?> // <span class="label success">Live</span>
<?php echo $item['Item']['flagged'] ? '<span class="label alert">Flagged</span>' : ''; ?> // nothing
```

Why are these behaving differently from eachother?
They're both set to tinyint(1) not null. Live default is 1, flagged default is 0.

The element I'm checking against - in MySQL is showing Flagged as 1.

Comment: What does `var_dump($item['Item']['flagged']);` show before you run the shorthand if statement for it?

Comment: d'oh! let me try that.

Comment: I am indeed getting `bool(true)` for `$item['Item']['flagged']`

Comment: That's weird. What happens if you change both of them to `echo ($item) ? '<span class="label TYPE">TEXT</span>' : '';` ?

Comment: Nevermind - it was an error in the actual HTML.

Comment: But I wouldn't have figured it out without the affirmative true. thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you somewhat @itamar :)